# Enviar varios parámetros en la URL de Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

Hola buenos días estoy viendo como poder enviar 2 parámetros por la ulr de Ajax, sé que esos parámetros lo puedo enviar por el atributo de data: que tiene Ajax pero esa es como mi segunda opción si es que no existe forma de enviarlo por la url. Actualmente estoy enviando 1 dato y requiero enviar la variable petición como segundo parámetro.
Les anexo mi petición Ajax la cual estoy enviando a una función de CodeIgniter.

> Petición Ajax

```js
function addInstitucionalAlumnoAjax() {
          
  var id_matricula = document.getElementById("form-alumno-matricula").value;

  // Tipo de peticiones : 
  // 1 = Uno por Uno
  // 2 = Masiva

  var peticion = 1;

  $.ajax({
      url : "<?php echo base_url('Alumnos/addInstitucionalAlumnoAjax/')?>"+id_matricula,
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#modal-form-alumno').serialize(),
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: '¡Buen trabajo!',
          text: '¡Los accesos se crearon correctamente!'
        });
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
          alert("datos incorrectos");
      }
  });
}
```

> Función CodeIgniter

```
public function addInstitucionalAlumnoAjax($id_matricula, $peticion) {
    if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
        redirect(base_url().'Auth');
    }

    try {

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
    } //./catch
}
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las [`QueryString`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) se forman así:

> PROTO://HOST:PORT/PATH?PARAM1=VALUE1&PARAM2=VALUE2&...&PARAMn=VALUEn

Si nos fijamos en tu URL:

> Alumnos/addInstitucionalAlumnoAjax/')?>"+id_matricula

vemos que estás enviando tus argumentos como parte **del `PATH`**. Por lo tanto, basta con añadir ese parámetro adicional usando el separador `/`.
Cambia tu petición a

```
$.ajax({
      url : "<?php echo base_url('Alumnos/addInstitucionalAlumnoAjax/')?>"+id_matricula+"/"+peticion,
      type: "POST",
```

Comment: concuerdo con tu respuesta pero le recomiendas algo distinto ya que estás haciendo que se mande el valor de los parametros pero sin la key no se si estoy equivocado pero no debería de ser en ves de id_matricula+"&"+peticion mandarlo así: "id_matricula="id_matricula+"&peticion="+peticion??

Comment: @jorgeGomez Yo ni siquiera sabía que se podían mandar parámetros así, sin *key*. Pero el parece que lo está haciendo (según su código). Todos los días se aprende algo :-O

Comment: Bueno, que cosas, si no le funciona pues ya tiene al menos el comentario de como debe hacerlo, sugiero que le coloques la segunda opción. con los parametros del otro modo por si las moscas

Comment: @jorgeGomez Supongo que al navegador en realidad le dará igual, mandará la cadena *QueryString* *tal cual* y listo. Lo que no se es si PHP será capaz de interpretarlo así, o el *framework* `codeigniter-3`. Bueno, si no le funciona, que comente.

Comment: al parecer si le funcionó

Comment: Je je ... Curioso ... 

Comment: Me manda el siguiente error addInstitucionalAlumnoAjax is not defined lo hice de la siguiente forma url : "<?php echo base_url('Alumnos/addInstitucionalAlumnoAjax/')?>id_matricula="id_matricula+"&peticion="+peticion,

Comment: An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: @Javierfr A ver, entonces, ¿ Te ha funcionado **sin** las *keys* o has tenido que ponerlas o no te funciona de ninguna manera ?

Comment: de ninguna forma haaaaaaaa

Comment: con las keys me manda el sguiente error:Bad Request 
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: @Javierfr El mensaje es claro, estás usando algún caracter **no válido** en una URI: ¿ estás usando espacios, caracteres acentuados, etc ? Como valores de tus variables `id_matricula` o `peticion`

Comment: No, solo los que ves antes de hacer mi petición con Ajax

Comment: id_matricula son numero sin espacio ni algun caracter extraño

Comment: @Javierfr No veo lo que hay en `id_matricula`, lo tomas de tu HTML.

Comment: si lo tomo de mi HTML y son numeros, ejemplo : 000008080

Comment: ¡ Jajajaja ! Ya lo ví. jejeje. **NO** estás mandando parámetros en la URL

Comment: @Javierfr Cámbialo por `+id_matricula+"/"+peticion`. Estas mandando tus valores como partes del `PATH`, de la ruta.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya quedo, I LOVE YOU . Edita tu respuesta